# hiding single entries from a list from my database

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2, hide

I want the manager to be able to hide comments made so that customers wont see bad/inappropriate reviews.  Because i've used jinja, tits just one line of code I have to write and it will loop through the data in the database. However when I assign the id to the list tag it only removes the first item which isnt what i want.  i want the user to be able to choose what comment they wish to hide/remove and have it removed from view once the button is activated.

i thought to pass in {{ record[0] }} in the id; this is the index number for the database - but this is still not working..

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<h1>Aurous 79® Admin</h1>
<br>
<p>Click here to run <a href="/adminreports">Reports</a> from your feedback form</p>
<br><br>
<h2>Manage Customer Guestbook</h2>
<p>Here you can manage the posts being viewed below.</p>
<h3>Customer Guestbook:</h3>
<ul id="customer_comments">
<p>| Name | Comments | Date | Time | Edit Entry |</p>
{% for record in data %}
    <li id="{{ record[0] }}">| {{ record[1] }} | {{ record[12] }} | {{ record[14] }} | {{ record[15] }} |</li><button onclick="myFunction()">Hide</button>
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("{{ record[0] }}").innerHTML = "";
    }
    </script>

{% endfor %}
</ul>
<p>Click here to <a href="/logout">Logout</a></p>

{% endblock %}
```

once i activate the button nothing happens; i've inspected the page and the index position matches my database so I don't know where i'm going wrong'

Comment: You can't create the same function name multiple times. It will get overwritten every iteration of the loop. Only the last instance will work

Comment: So how would I hide an unwanted comment?